# Inserting optical elements into a ring laser gyroscope to sense all three axes

Tags: design-alternative, attitude-determination-and-control, optical, sensors, gyroscope

Ring laser gyroscopes (RLGs) leverage the physics of ring laser interferometers and the [Sagnac effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagnac_effect) to sense rotation in a single plane. My understanding of RLGs is that they are independent systems within a spacecraft's attitude determination subsystem; my understanding of how this impacts what attitude control devices (actuators) is more limited, but I think it best to clearly differentiate between the sensor (RLG) and actuators (torquers, control moment gyros, thruster, etc.).

Could you possibly insert *moving* optical elements (crystals, wave-plates) into the ring laser interferometer by attaching them to the spacecraft such that they swivel according to the spacecraft's movement inside the RLG?

These optical elements are disk-like (just for the sake of this post) and have a small aperture held by a larger disk-like housing; they are mounted inside the RLG in the optical path of the laser it generates such that they move in pitch, yaw, and roll. They do two relevant things that my main question is about:

1. alter the polarization state of the laser
2. swivel on gimbals inside the RLG in such a way that they move in the pitch, yaw, and roll planes of your spacecraft but have limits on that motion otherwise light wouldn't pass through the aperture.

The change in polarization state to the laser caused by the elements can be mapped to precise changes in the spacecraft's attitude. I am assuming that these optical elements are in the free-space optical paths of the RLG after the laser is generated/excited in the optical cavity. I don't think you can put optical elements in the optical cavity itself?

**Would mounting moving parts to the spacecraft to be a part of the attitude system even be possible? Does an RLG need to be a closed system is perhaps a better question? Would there be too much vibration (depending on spacecraft complexity and size) caused by the spacecraft for reliable optical measurements to be made?**

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say it's not possible, but I would be shocked if it were an improvement on a ring laser gyroscope in any metric, including attitude resolution.

Comment: I wish there could be an Optics and Photonics SE site for this class of topic. But for this particular question, it's not clear to me 1) without a diagram, what you mean, 2) what would make one think that doing anything to a system that already measures attitude with high precision work better by sticking stuff into it. Can you elaborate?

Comment: "*swivel on gimbals*". This appears to be stabilized platform IMU (as opposed to strap down IMU). Would your system be affected by gimbal lock ?